# How to requestFocus on EditText from onClick function of button?

Tags: android, android-edittext

This is my code.
Focus is not coming on EditText(named search). And I don't have any other EditText in the current layout.

```
    handle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            search.requestFocus();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private EditText text1;
private EditText text2;
private Button button1;
private Button button2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    text2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view.getId() == R.id.button){
        text1.requestFocus();
    }
    else if(view.getId() == R.id.button2){
        text2.requestFocus();
    }
}
}
```

The requestFocus() is enough.No additional attributes "focusable" set,the EditText was added as default behavior.
May you forget add like "button1.setOnClickListener(this);" to make the button responsible?
[image: Demo screenshot on Android 5.0]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code to your xml!

```
<EditText
      android:focusable="true"
      <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: It didn't work. :(
Search is actually a SearchView. And I have kept setIconifiedByDefault(false)

Comment: Remove the request focus line from the program and add the 2 lines in EditText to your EditText in your xml

Answer (score 0):

If you want your Keyboard to popup then try this code

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
    .showSoftInput(myEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

Also add in your `Mainfest`

`<activity android:name=".first" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible">`

Comment: If I set this in manifest, it will display the keyboard as I enter activity. But I have a SlidingDrawer and SearchView in that drawer. When user clicks handle, focus should come on searchview and keyboard should appear.

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
    search.setFocusable(true);
    search.requestFocus();
```